# Create ID with information based on dict keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with the following input

| client | type | country | potential |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Private | USA | low |
| Client 2 | Private | Ireland | high |
| Client 3 | Institutional | GB | mid |
| Client 4 | Institutional | GB | mid |
| Client 5 | Institutional | GB | mid |

I want to create a ID for each client.
The ID should **not be random** (I tried using the `uuid` package) but contain information about the client and seperate clients with same attributes.

```
ID_classification = {'type':{'A':'Private','B':'Institutional'},
                     'country':{'1':'USA','2':'GB','3':'Ireland'},
                     'potential':{'1':'low','2':'mid','3':'high'}}
```

The ID-pattern could then look like this (have not settled on a final pattern yet)

> type.key-country.key-potential.key-unique_id

Resulting in:

| id | client | type | country | potential |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-1-1-1 | Client 1 | Private | USA | low |
| A-3-3-1 | Client 2 | Private | Ireland | high |
| B-2-2-1 | Client 3 | Institutional | GB | mid |
| B-2-2-2 | Client 4 | Institutional | GB | mid |
| B-2-2-3 | Client 5 | Institutional | GB | mid |

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# reorganize your mapping dictionary
# to have the key: value in correct order
mapper = {k1: {k: v for v, k in d.items()}
          for k1, d in ID_classification.items()}

# map all desired columns
df['id'] = df[list(mapper)].apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper[s.name])).agg('-'.join, axis=1)

# add unique id
df['id'] += '-' + df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
     client           type  country potential       id
0  Client 1        Private      USA       low  A-1-1-1
1  Client 2        Private  Ireland      high  A-3-3-1
2  Client 3  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-1
3  Client 4  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-2
4  Client 5  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-3
```

Comment: thanks. Suppose the first key is not a `str` but also a `float`. Running the ID only with `floats` gives me a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`. How would I modify your code snip to adapt?

Comment: Then use `mapper = {k1: {k: str(v) for v, k in d.items()} for k1, d in ID_classification.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#swap key value in inner dictionaries
d = {k:{v1:k1 for k1, v1 in v.items()} for k, v in ID_classification.items()}

#map columns by d with join together by -
s = pd.DataFrame([df[k].map(v) for k, v in d.items()]).agg('-'.join)

#added counter column by Series s
df['id'] = s + '-' + df.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
     client           type  country potential       id
0  Client 1        Private      USA       low  A-1-1-1
1  Client 2        Private  Ireland      high  A-3-3-1
2  Client 3  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-1
3  Client 4  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-2
4  Client 5  Institutional       GB       mid  B-2-2-3
```